# Problem: GNU octave displaying every line of any program run in command window

Tags: octave

I'm new to octave (and any kind of programing in general). It doesn't matter the code that I run, every time i do it the command window displays every line of it and every step, which can get overwhelming when doing cyclical algorithms. And this doesn't seem to happened to every other user I personally know. Even using exactly the same .m file, i get all the lines displayed and some other person doesn't.
I've searched in every configuration window possible, I tried reinstalling but nothing helped. And I've seen nobody else having this problem, is it just a configuration that I'm not aware of?

I'm running Octave 5.2.0 in Linux Mint 19.3

Comment: You have `echo on`. You need to turn it `off`. https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.0/Diary-and-Echo-Commands.html

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding ";" at the end of your command lines ?
Basically if your code is something like:

```
x=5
y=4
```

Then your command window will display:

```
x=5
y=4
```

Whereas if you add the semicolons at the end of your code like so:

```
x=5;
y=4;
```

Then your values will be store and registered but nothing will be displayed in the command window.